# Trailing Zeroes in the factorial of a number

Tags: python

I have been trying to solve a program which is: Count the number of trailing zeroes in the factorial of the number and here's my code. It runs fine on my PC but shows" runtime error (NZEC)" when run on judge.

```
def fact(n):#calculate factorial of the number
  i =2
  temp =1
  while i<= n :
    temp*=i
    i+=1
  return temp



def zero_count(n):#calculate number of trailing zeroes
   F = fact(n)
   F =str(F)
   R = F[::-1]
   Rnum = int(R)
   Rnum = str(Rnum)
   return(len(R)-len(Rnum))



 def main():
     cases = int(input())#total number of cases
     i = 1
     num = []
     while i<=cases:
        n=int(input())
        num.append(zero_count(n))
        i+=1
     for item in num:
        print(item)
        print()
 main()
```

Comment: sorry to trouble you but i don't see how ?

Comment: You need to change your approach.  Instead of actually computing the factorial and then going via strings, can you think of another way to figure out how many trailing zeros n! has?  (Hint: 4! has 0 trailing zeros; 5!, 6!, 7!, 8!, and 9! all have 1; 10! has two.  How many does 25! have?)

Comment: Don't be scared of using websearch. I bet you'll be amazed at what happens when you put your question title or keywords into a search engine.

Comment: I'd like to post the solution in python but unfortunately the question was marked as duplicate and the other question is for Ruby and not python...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that counts the trailing zeros in a number:

```
def count_trailing_zeros(n):
    ntz = 0
    while True:
        if n % 10 == 0:
            ntz += 1
            n = n/10
        else:
            break
    return ntz
```

Having calculated your factorial, simply run the result through this function.

Comment: *Having calculated your factorial.* That's just it. The key is that you should not calculate the factorial's value.

Comment: That will not be efficient. There are ways to find the trailing zeros without calculating the factorial itself which may take some time.